# Need to create a neural network for 2D input and 2D output. Getting error when checking target:

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

//x_train.shape = (12600,58196)
//y_train.shape = (12600,20)
The y output is an array of 1s and 0s for each input.
Following is the code I am trying to write.

```
    """
    buildModel_DNN_Tex(shape, nClasses,dropout)
    Build Deep neural networks Model for text classification
    Shape is input feature space
    nClasses is number of classes
    """
    model = Sequential()
    node = 512 # number of nodes
    nLayers = 4 # number of  hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(node,input_dim=shape,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
#     for i in range(0,nLayers):
#         model.add(Dense(node,input_dim=node,activation='relu'))
#         model.add(Dropout(dropout))
#     model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(nClasses, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

When I try to fit the model with:

```
model_DNN = Build_Model_DNN_Text(X_train_tfidf.shape[1], 20)
model_DNN.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train,
                              validation_data=(X_test_tfidf, y_test),
                              epochs=10,
                              batch_size=128,
                              verbose=2)
predicted = model_DNN.predict(X_test_tfidf)
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, predicted))
```

get an error of: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_83 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (20,)

Can You please help??

Comment: What is the value of nClasses? It seems to be one

Comment: You probably also want to change the last activation to be sigmoid as you are predicting an array of 1s and 0s, not probabilities. Then, you would need to change the loss to be binary cross entropy.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy it is 20, as it is passed as parameter

Comment: Ah yes, you should not be using sparse categorical crossentropy, as it assumes that your labels are integers, what exactly are your labels? one hot encoded?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy yes, they are one hot encoded already, with 20 columns of 0 or 1

Comment: Then just use the standard categorical crossentropy loss

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy actually binary crossentropy worked. Thanks!

Comment: If labels are one-hot encoded (one class per label), then you should use the categorical_crossentropy loss, not the binary one.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy ohh, thanks for the input!!